# PostgreSQL TO_CHAR() Remove Padding on Month Field

Tags: postgresql, to-char

Hopefully and easy adjustment.  I've googled and not found anything on this.  I'm using the DBvis Client to run queries against a Postgres database table.

I've used the to_char() function quite a bit with Oracle and PostgreSQL queries, but guess I've never noticed this behavior.

`SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'Month DD, YYYY') AS DATE_CREATED...;`

In the result set, the month field is being padded with spaces out to 9 spaces, then the day and year:

```
February  26, 2018
January   01, 2000
July      23, 2014
September 01, 2015
December  15, 2015
May       31, 2016
```

I know now, from the docs, that this is the way the `month` format works, but is there a way to get the full month without the extra padding?  I'd like it to look like so:

```
February 26, 2018
January 01, 2000
July 23, 2014
September 01, 2015
December 15, 2015
May 31, 2016
```

Each date will be followed by the content of a text field and I think they would just read easier if there were only one space between the Month and Day.

`May       31, 2016  This is my text notes for this record`   The date portion of this record is not aesthetically pleasing or easy on the eyes.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the "fill mode" `FM` which - in contrast to its name - does **not** fill the value with spaces:

```
TO_CHAR(created_at, 'FMMonth DD, YYYY')
```

Comment: Thank you, so much.  That works great.  Obviously never seen that before, but will remember in the future.  Much appreciated. --jc